# Testing scroll events using React testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I am developing one responsive component, and for mobile screen, i am showing some shadow on each or either border using css & `onscroll` event. this is working fine when i am testing manually.

Now to test this, we are using React testing library -

```
fireEvent.scroll(ctrEl, {target :{ scrollX : 40})
```

but this is not moving the scrollbar, and neither applying the correct class, so test cases are failing and decreasing the test coverage drastically.

Any idea to test this..?